# Как отключить автоформатирование в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как отключить автоформатирование в wordpress?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_wptexturize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключить можно добавив в файл functions.php вашей активной темы такие строчки:
в записях

```
 remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
 remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
 remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
```